# Spell checking with python and win32com in * .docx - problems with * .docx

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, win32com, spell-checking, python-docx

I have a problem that I have completely decomposed of. I came to this method for a long time and sniff.

I download text from websites and check its spelling. It was hard to check this with a dictionary (time and hardware), so I download all the text to a .txt file and then copy it to a.docx file, where it automatically checks Microsoft Word for spellings highlighting the errors in red.

I found how to get spelling errors from a .docx file in python (library win32com.client)
And it was fine, I started writing a program to save text from web pages to a .docx file and test the spelling of it right away, but here I get an error.

```python
 # file newfile.docx is a file where i save all text from site
 
 docX = docx.Document()
 
 def imatoohard():
     #time.sleep(10)
     wordapp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
     worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(r"C:\Python\newfile.docx")
     print("start as optimist")
     time.sleep(1)
     if worddoc.SpellingErrors.Count:
         print("0x21")
         for err in worddoc.SpellingErrors:
             print("0x33")
             docX.add_paragraph(http_source_str)


         worddoc.ActiveWindow.Close()
         
imatoohard()
```

this is just a piece of code to check the spelling in the file (above) and the writing itself to the file is below, the simplest method:

```
doc1 = docx.Document()
doc1.add_paragraph(some_data_text)
doc1.sve("newfile.docx")
```

Everything is fine, the first code checks the spelling and the second code saves the text to the docx file format. But the spell checker does not check the spelling on the file created by program two.

When i open, type text and save manually everything is fine when i do the same with the program the docx file is in 'compatibility mode'
and it does not detect or set the language, I have to manually translate using Microsoft Word settings and only then it detects the language and highlights misspelled words, and only then the first program works.

Is there any way to do that? I've been sitting on it for so long that I don't know if I will give up. It would be very useful for me, because I have a good thousand pages (one hundred thousand words) to check.
Has anyone had contact with this?

Settings such as:

```
file = open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
```

do not work for a .docx file

Comment: Have you tried explicitly triggering a spell-check on the win32com side? This `Document.CheckSpelling` method documented here seems to be how you would do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.checkspelling